# Problem with Deprecation Synchronous XMLHttpRequest JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my code.

I want to use ajax response for global variables so that the variable can be used in other functions.

But I got a warning from the console that Syncronous will be deprecated.

Is there an alternative to running it?

**session.js**

```
let SESSION     = {}

const sessionController = (() => {

const getSession = () => {
    if (TOKEN) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: `${BASE_URL}int/setting/user_info`,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            async: false,
            global: false,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD))
                xhr.setRequestHeader("SCM-INT-KEY", TOKEN)
            },
            success: function (res) {
                SESSION = res.data
            },
            error: function (err) {
                window.location.replace(`${BASE_URL}private`)
            }
        });

    } else {
        window.location.replace(`${BASE_URL}private`)
    }
}

return {
    init: () => {
        getSession()
    }
}
})();



sessionController.init()
```

**app.js**

```
const renderApp = (() => {
const DOM = {
    menu: '#menu',
    content: '#content'
}

return {
    renderNavigation: () => {

        let { level } = SESSION
        let menu = '';

        switch (level) {
            case 'Admin':
                menu += `<h1> Navbar Admin </h1>`
                break;

            case 'Finance':
                menu += `<h1> Navbar Finance </h1>`
                break;

            case 'Warehouse':
                menu += `<h1> Navbar Warehouse </h1>`
                break;

            default:

                break;
        }

        $(DOM.menu).html(menu);
    },
    renderPage: (page) => {
        $(DOM.content).html(page);
    }
}
})();

const appController = ((UI) => {
const getPage = path => {
    let FULLPATH = `${BASE_URL}${path}`

    let { level } = SESSION

    if (path === 'dashboard') {
        FULLPATH = `${path}/${level}`
    }

    $.get(FULLPATH, function (page) {
        UI.renderPage(page)
    })
}

const setRoute = () => {
    if (!location.hash) {
        location.hash = '#/dashboard';
    } else {
        let path = location.hash.substr(2);
        getPage(path);
    }

    $(window).on('hashchange', function () {
        let path = location.hash.substr(2);
        getPage(path);
    });
}

return {
    init: () => {
        UI.renderNavigation(),
        setRoute()
    }
}
})(renderApp);

$(document).ready(function () {
    appController.init();
})
```

Please help me..
Give me some example to solve this

Thanks

Comment: *"Is there an alternative to running it?"* like asynchronous? yes. Just set `async: true`

Comment: you could use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: @Thomas if i set async to true, global variable is object null

Comment: yes, if you set async to true, you have to wait for the request to finish, before you can access the value. At the moment you are freezing your entire page untill the request is finished, including the code that accesses the variable. That's how your current code works. Check out Promises.